# VBA. How to get user-defined data type field by name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have

```
Public Type MyType
  varA as A
  varB as B
  varC as C
End Type

Dim MyData as MyType
Dim a As String
```

And now:

```
a = "varC"
```

And I want to get this (`MyData.varC`):

```
f = MyData.$a
```

How I can do it?

Comment: AFAIK you can't with a UDT. With a class you'd use `Callbyname` but that requires an Object, not a UDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are after is CallByName, which you can find over here on this webpage:

[URL to CallByName info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278760%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Here's an example to hold the result of a property, according to the string value of var a:

```
aVarToHoldResult = CallByName MyData, a, VbGet
```

EDIT : Yep, points Rory for pointing out the problem structures vs classes. I suggest getting familiar with classes if you care about code maintenance anyhow.